# Subir datos en Firebase android

Tags: android, firebase

Intento crear una base de datos con los Users pero me da fallo en la linea de setValue, creo recordar que alguna vez si que me ha funcionado y no se cual es el problema ahora, agradeceria la ayuda

```
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        // User is signed in

        Toast.makeText( this, "Bienvenido "+user.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        navMenuName.setText( user.getDisplayName());
        navMenuEmail.setText( user.getEmail());
        Picasso.get().load(photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl()).into(navMenuImage);

        email=navMenuEmail.getText().toString();
        names=navMenuName.getText().toString();
        uiD=user.getUid();


    } else {
        // Create and launch sign-in intent
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()))
                        .setLogo(R.drawable.splashscreen)
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);
     }


        FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = database.getReference();

        users= new User(databaseReference.push().getKey(),names,email,photoUrl);
        databaseReference.child(USERS_NODE).child( uiD).setValue(users);// aqui nos da el fallo



    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source:10)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.lujan.confirmaciones.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:214)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué representa el `.child(uiD)`, eso es un nodo, o sería el valor `ID` del usuario que quieres agregar?

Comment: Asi es la base de datos que se me creaba antes y ahora me da el fallo, comentar que el codigo esta en onCreate

Comment: La doc dice que `push` sirve justamente para crearte un ID único. Cuando usas `push` sólo tienes que preocuparte de introducir los datos. Prueba así: `FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
databaseReference = database.getReference();

users=new User(uiD,names,email,photoUrl);
DatabaseReference userRef=databaseReference.child(USERS_NODE).push();
userRef.setValueAsync(user);`

Comment: a userRef no le deja poner el metodo setValueAsync

Comment: ¿Puedes confirmar que **efectivamente** la constante `USERS_NODE` equivale a `Users`?

Comment: private static final String USERS_NODE = "Users"; // asi lo tengo puesto; lo Raro es que el codigo es el mismo que tengo en otra activity y ahi si que me funciona, la unica diferencia es que este que pongo esta en onCreate

Comment: Prueba de este modo: `FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
databaseReference = database.getReference();
users=new User(uiD,names,email,photoUrl);

DatabaseReference usersRef = databaseReference.child(USERS_NODE);

usersRef.push().setValueAsync(user);` Confirma si se crea un objeto `users` válido. Yo he supuesto que el parámetro `uiD` era el correcto para almacenar en la clave `idU` de Firebase.

Comment: Ahora almenos no me da ningun tipo de error, pero el setValueAsync sigue siendo un metodo invalido, al quitarlo la app funciona pero sin subir los datos. Gracias por las molestias

Comment: ¿Qué arroja si depuras el valor `usersRef`? Otro modo que podrías probar sería: `DatabaseReference usersRef = databaseReference.child(USERS_NODE);
DatabaseReference pushedUser = usersRef.push();
String userId = pushedUser.getKey();   

users= new User(userId,names,email,photoUrl);
databaseReference.child(USERS_NODE).child(userId).setValue(users);`

Comment: userRef funciona bien, lo que parece que esta dando fallo es el setvalue; y ahora databaseReference es null. No se preocupe que durante la semana con algo mas de tiempo dare la solucion y la publicare. Gracias por su ayuda!!!

Comment: Yo creé un nodo de prueba llamado `posts` y probé el siguiente código: `DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference newPost = root.child("posts").push();
        newPost.setValue(new Post("gracehop", "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"));`  El mismo me funciona a la perfección. Es cierto que no me aceptaba el `setValueAsync` pero con `setValue` solo, se crea un post cada vez que llamo la activity. El código está en el `onCreate`. Otra cosa que debes verificar es si no hay alguna regla que está restringiendo la escritura.

Comment: A.Cedano, he descubierto gracias a tu ultimo post que el fallo lo tenia en el Uri que le pasaba, lo he convertido en String y ahora si que me funciona, ahora me crea de nuevo la base de datos en Firebase, luego despues de trabajar le volvere a echar un vistazo para dar con la solucion definitiva. Muchas gracias por su ayuda y por su paciencia. Un saludo

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Saludos.

Comment: deberias usar un HashMap si quieres subir varios datos al mismo tiempo, sino obtener cada uno y subirlo con distintos setvalue